# Creating dynamic controls bound to Tables WPF & LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, linq, entity-framework

I wrote a post with 2 questions and was told to split them to 2 different posts,
since one of them was solved here is the other one :

I have a problem in understanding some basic concepts here i think ... I am working on creating a a project for managing a complex database, (i am using linq to entities for my database that is in ms-sql 2012 and WPF )

I want to create a generic view for editing (remove update and insert) a large amount of tables from the database, i have no problem creating the list of tables manually but after that how can i manage it in a generic way ? linq to entities does not allow doing something like :

```
string tableName = listbox.selectedItem.value;
var a = from p in db.tables[tableName] select p;
```

and even if i make all this manually for each table how can i create a UI that edits the information ? i need to dynamically create a form/view/user_control for editing that will contain items such as textbox and datetimepickers for each column... but i cannot make a generic selection for a table ...

Just to make things clear, i have some nice experience in .net tech but WPF and LINQ is new to me, i could easily create all Above in asp.net or windows form application using direct contact to the SQL DB without linq therefore i understand i have a problem with some basics understanding and would to get answers to my 2 questions and will be more than happy to get directions to relevant tutorials

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of using Entity Framework is that it allows to have a level of abstraction from the DB (that's what an ORM does). If you need to expose your DB tables directly to the UI you'd better resort to plain old ADO.Net `System.Data.DataSet etc`, and the WPF `DataGrid` has an `AutoGenerateColumns` property to auto generate the grid columns based on the DataTable columns.

Also, doing something like `listbox.selectedItem.value` in WPF is not recommended. You should not manipulate UI Elements' properties in code. You'd better have a look at the MVVM pattern.